# Change whmcs template from hook

Tags: php, templates, smarty, whmcs

I too searched in all forums and even I post my question on the whmcs forum but no response. What i need is that i create an addon in modules and i want to change template (from six to five) in hooks of this addon. The aim is to change template for specific clients.
I already test to change the GET var but not working :

```
$_GET['systpl'] = 'five';
```

I also tested this but the css files don't load. It redirect me to home :

```
global $smarty;
$template = $smarty->getTemplateVars('template');
$template = 'six';
$smarty->assign('template', $template);
$template = $smarty->getTemplateVars('template');
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this in one of my products - to get this to work, you have to pull the global $systpl variable:

```
global $systpl;
$systpl = $tpl;

$GLOBALS['_SESSION']['Template']    = $tpl;
$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['Template']      = $tpl;
```

Where $tpl is the template name you are looking to set, in your case 'five'.  You have to also set the GLOBALS variables there so that the user session is maintained with that template and so that the system knows to use that template name when pulling from the config.

Hope that is of help.

Comment: thanks this work great, but how do I set back to the default template?

Comment: Solution for my aswer:
<?php

use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;
use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

define("CLIENTAREA", true);

// Set the template you want to use for the custom page BEFORE init.php is called
$GLOBALS['_REQUEST']['systpl'] = 'five';

require("init.php");

// WHATEVER YOU ARE DOING IN HERE

// Set the session back to the default template:
$GLOBALS['_SESSION']['Template'] = 'six'; 

$ca->output();

Answer (score 1):

In WHMCS to load another template folder for specified page, I did:

```
<?php

use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;
use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

define("CLIENTAREA", true);

// Set the template you want to use for the custom page BEFORE init.php is called
$GLOBALS['_REQUEST']['systpl'] = 'five';

require("init.php");

// WHATEVER YOU ARE DOING IN HERE

// Set the session back to the default template:
$GLOBALS['_SESSION']['Template'] = 'six'; 

$ca->output();
```